# Minitest: How to stub/mock the file result of Kernel.open on a URL

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I have been trying to use Minitest to test my code ([full repo](https://github.com/kkirsche/elasticsearch_update)) but am having trouble with one method which downloads a SHA1 hash from a .txt file on a website and returns the value.

Method:

```
def download_remote_sha1
  @log.info('Downloading Elasticsearch SHA1.')

  @remote_sha1 = ''
  Kernel.open(@verify_url) do |file|
    @remote_sha1 = file.read
  end

  @remote_sha1 = @remote_sha1.split(/\s\s/)[0]

  @remote_sha1
end
```

You can see that I log what is occurring to the command line, create  an object to hold my SHA1 value, open the url (e.g. https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.4.2.deb.sha1.txt)

I then split the string so that I only have the SHA1 value.

The problem is that during a test, I want to stub the [`Kernel.open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5//libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-c-open) which uses OpenURI to open the URL. I would like to ensure that I'm not actually reaching out to download any file, but rather I'm just passing the block my own mock IO object testing just that it correctly splits stuff.

I attempted it like the block below but when `@remote_sha1 = file.read` occurs the file item is nil.

```
@mock_file = Minitest::Mock.new
@mock_file.expect(:read, 'd377e39343e5cc277104beee349e1578dc50f7f8  elasticsearch-1.4.2.deb')

Kernel.stub :open, @mock_file do
  @downloader = ElasticsearchUpdate::Downloader.new(hash, true)
  @downloader.download_remote_sha1.must_equal 'd377e39343e5cc277104beee349e1578dc50f7f8'
end
```

Comment: Hi,  Can you please accept matt's answer instead of mine?  He posted the correct answer long before I figured out what was going on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `stub` is what you want the *return value* to be for the duration of your test, but the way `Kernel.open` is used here requires the value it yields to the block to be changed instead.

You can achieve this by providing a third argument. Try changing the call to `Kernel.stub` to

```
Kernel.stub :open, true, @mock_file do
  #...
```

Note the extra argument `true`, so that `@mock_file` is now the third argument and will be yielded to the block. The actual value of the second argument doesn’t really matter in this case, you might want to use `@mock_file` there too to more closely correspond to how `open` behaves.

Answer (score 4):

I was working on this question too, but `matt` figured it out first.  To add to what `matt` posted:

When you write:

```
Kernel.stub(:open, @mock_file) do
  #block code
end
```

...that means when `Kernel.open()` is called--in *any* code, *anywhere* before the stub() block ends--the return value of `Kernel.open()` will be @mock_file.  However, you never use the return value of Kernel.open() in your code:

```
Kernel.open(@verify_url) do |f|
  @remote_sha1 = f.read
end
```

If you wanted to use the return value of Kernel.open(), you would have to write:

```
return_val = Kernel.open(@verify_url) do |f|
  @remote_sha1 = f.read
end

#do something with return_val
```

Therefore, the return value of Kernel.open() is irrelevant in your code--which means the second argument of stub() is irrelevant.

A careful examination of the [source code for stub()](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/mock.rb) reveals that stub() takes a third argument--an argument which will be passed to a *block* specified after the stubbed method call.  You, in fact, have specified a block after your stubbed Kernel.open() method call:

```
stubbed method call -+       +- start of block
            |        |       |
            V        V       V
   Kernel.open(@verify_url) do |f|
      @remote_sha1 = f.read
    end
     ^
     |
   end of block
```

So, in order to pass @mockfile to the block you need to specify it as the third argument to Kernel.stub():

```
Kernel.stub(:open, 'irrelevant', @mock_file) do 

end
```

Here is a full example for future searchers:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Dog
  def initialize
    @verify_url = 'http://www.google.com'
  end

  def download_remote_sha1
    @remote_sha1 = ''

    Kernel.open(@verify_url) do |f|
      @remote_sha1 = f.read
    end

    #puts @remote_sha1[0..300]
    @remote_sha1 = @remote_sha1.split(" ")[0]  #Using a single space for the split() pattern will split on contiguous whitespace.

  end
end

#Dog.new.download_remote_sha1

describe 'downloaded file' do
  it 'should be an sha1 code' do
    @mock_file = Minitest::Mock.new
    @mock_file.expect(:read, 'd377e39343e5cc277104beee349e1578dc50f7f8  elasticsearch-1.4.2.deb')

    Kernel.stub(:open, 'irrelevant', @mock_file) do 
      @downloader = Dog.new 
      @downloader.download_remote_sha1.must_equal 'd377e39343e5cc277104beee349e1578dc50f7f8'
    end
  end
end
```

xxx